# How to perform task after mixed async operation( callback & promise ) finished?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback, promise

I'm writing some nodejs applications. my application has some dependencies on some npm modules.

In a task, it involves two async operation, the two async operation is in the form of callback and promise. Below I put some sample code:

```
// the task which should be performed after async operation
var myTask = function(){
  // do something
}

// first async operation in the form of callback
cbapi(myTask)

// second async operation in the form of promise
promiseapi()
.then(myTask)
```

In above example, `myTask` will be performed twice when first async and second async operation is finished. But what I want is to perform it once only after both async operation if finished.

Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: Don't mix callbacks and promises, promisify callback apis and then call the promisified apis

Comment: Without seeing code its difficult to help you, but what Esailija told is like a rule of thumb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct a new Promise around your callback function call, and use `Promise.all` on both calls:

```
Promise.all([new Promise(resolve => cbapi(resolve)), promiseapi()])
.then(myTask)
.catch(e => console.error(e));
```

`myTask` will be called with an array containing the results from the two calls.

Comment: This way if `cbapi` results in an error, it will still resolve the promise. It should reject instead.

Comment: @Louy as written, there is no way for the OP's `cbapi` to fail asynchronously (after it has returned), so my answer is appropriate given those constraints. To be able to fail asynchronously, `cbapi` would need to take two arguments: one success callback and one failure callback, and we'd then have it wrapped with `new Promise((resolve, reject) => cbapi(resolve, reject))`.

Comment: how did you know that `cbapi` wouldn't fail? if it's based on the sample code in the question then I think this is a wrong assumption. callbacks have a standard that should be followed.

Comment: I base my answers on the question yes. The OP's sample code shows wanting to run `myTask` after two asynchronous operations, regardless of any asynchronous failure it seems, since `myTask` takes no arguments.

Answer (score 2):

As *@esaukuha* suggested, you should promisify your callback apis and then use them.

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
  cbapi((err, result) => {
    if (err) reject(err);
    else resolve(result);
  })
)
  .then(myTask) // ... chain
```

I have a small [npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-cb) just for this.

```
import fromCallback from 'promise-cb/from';
fromCallback(cb => cbapi(cb))
  .then(myTask) // ... chain
```

Comment: `cbapi` takes one argument indeed. my answer only passes one argument (the lambda function.)

Comment: Right, I meant that `myTask` does not take any arguments, whereas you're assuming an error argument and a result argument.

Comment: `myTask` takes no arguments here though. I'm just creating a standard promise out of `cbapi` and calling `myTask` after it's done.

Comment: Yes, but you're assuming that `cbapi` calls its callback with certain arguments that you made up and the OP never mentioned.

Comment: as I mentioned, it's a standard. unless you have a good reason not to, you should always follow (and assume following) the standard.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I wasn't aware of this common convention in node (neither was the OP apparently?)